# How to clean up this very simple Rails function?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to pretty up this Rails code?

```
def function
  if new_record?                      
    thing
  else
    thing + yet_another_thing
  end
end
```

I don't like the repetition of `thing` here, so I wonder if there's a cleaner way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the class of `thing`?

Comment: Ehm... is possible to have the output of thing.class call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for any objects that support +,  (even strings.)

```
 [thing, (yet_another_thing unless new_record?)].compact.inject(:+)
```

It's DRY and scary, like being trapped in a desert without any water.

---

You might also be able to get away with:

```
 thing.dup.tap{|t| t << yet_another_thing unless new_record?}
```

This won't work if thing is an integer (you can't dup it) and it also needs to support the << operator.

Also DRY but scary in a different way.

Comment: The same pattern works fine for strings: Just replace `inject(:+)` with `join`

Comment: the inject works with strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

What about ternary operator?

```
def function
  new_record? ? thing : (thing + yet_another_thing)
end
```

This would be a lot more helpful if we knew where you were using this or what is contained in the variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat `thing`, then this might be a solution.

```
def function
  result = thing
  result += yet_another_thing unless new_record?
  result
end
```

Comment: You are repeating `result` three times instead of repeating `thing` twice. I don't think it helps.

Comment: If _thing_ is a non-trivial expression or function call, then it is a helpful pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an in-line if

```
def function
  return thing if new_record?
  thing + yet_another_thing
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If `thing` and `yet_another_thing` are strings, you could do this:

```
thing + (yet_another_thing unless new_record?).to_s
```

Comment: They are not strings :-(

Answer (score 0):

If thing and yet_another_thing are methods you're calling:

```
def function
  thing
  yet_another_thing if new_record?
end
```